# Code shows nothing on wordpress: while (have_posts()) {the_post();?>

Tags: php, wordpress

I've put this code to the index.php on wordpress, but it doesn't show up anything. I thought it should shows all the posts latest to newest. Anyone can solve this?

```
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <div class="card-meta">
                    Đăng bởi <?php the_author(); ?> vào <?php the_time('j F, Y') ?> trong  <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_category_list(',') ?></a>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?>
                </p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Tìm hiểu thêm</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <?php }
            wp_reset_query(); 
        ?>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you using `while (have_posts()) {the_post();?>` in your code? You have it in your question title but not in the code itself. Also, are you sure `index.php` is the template that is displaying whatever page you are trying this on? Many themes have templates specifically for pages, posts, archives etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing half of a loop pretty much ...

If you want to use the post template that you have in you question, then you can do something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ):
    $i = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ):
        $i++;
        if ( $i > 1 ):
        echo '<hr>';
        endif; ?>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
                <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID); ?>" alt="Card Image">
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                </a>
                <div class="card-meta">
                    Đăng bởi <?php the_author(); ?> vào <?php the_time('j F, Y') ?> trong  <a href="#"><?php echo get_the_category_list(',') ?></a>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), 30); ?>
                </p>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-readmore">Tìm hiểu thêm</a>
            </div>
        </div>

<?php
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

Should be working.